# Ionic 2: create a custom picker

Tags: select, ionic2, picker

In my project, I've got a list of countries from a database. In Ionic 2, the select option is alert (popup). I don't need that, so my question:

**How can I create a custom picker for countries list?**

Comment: You should provide at least some code and at minimum a sample of the data you get as well as a definition of what you want to achieve (“custom”).

Answer (score 1):

I just build a similar component here, base on the low-level picker component.
https://github.com/raychenfj/ion-multi-picker

[Chinese City Picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQsFU.gif)

But its performance could depend on your data volume.

Answer (score 0):

Fengjun Chen thanks for designing the custom Picker control. 
Can you post the source for the source for the Advance usage example that you hosted on - https://raychenfj.github.io/ion-multi-picker/
Also it will help if you can post an example of how to access the events and how to style the control.